# Express CORs policy preventing Apollo client from fetching from server

Tags: reactjs, express, cors, graphql

I'm running a react dev server on `http://localhost:3000` and an express server on `http://localhost:8080` and am using an Apollo Client to query the server. To enable session data to be passed from client to server I have added the `credentials: "include"` parameter when initializing the Apollo Client.

I've added the following line in my express server (before the routes are defined) to configure cors:

`app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));`

However, when executing queries, the following error is thrown:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

Why is the header response showing up as `*`? Am I configuring CORs incorrectly or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem I was running into here was that despite enabling CORS for express:

```
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));
```

The GraphQL middleware was over-riding the setting. Make sure to pass the `cors: false` param as shown below if using an Apollo Server and associated middleware.

```
gqlServer.applyMiddleware({ app, path: "/graphql", cors: false });
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked for me. Question though; how can I be sure that cors isn't being disabled completely with this solution?

Comment: Try running your client from a different host. The core policy should block the requests

Comment: Will do, thanks. +1 to your solution as it seems to have worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for this man! I've been encountering this weird bug, i just need to turn off the cors on the graphql. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This error is a CORS error generated by the browser. use npm install --save http-proxy-middleware in your front end and add setupProxy.js file in frontend/src/setupProxy.js

> setupProxy.js

```js
//run defferent ports for website and api server 
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/api/', { target: 'http://localhost:8080/' })); //make change as per your application (So you can access your data on  http://localhost:8080/api/ )
};
```

**Alternate solution**

If you are using webpack dev server, here's another way to proxy requests without making changes on NodeJS. Adding this to package.json:

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

Should allow webpack to proxy requests made to `http://localhost:3000` to   `http://localhost:8080`.

But this would mean request will need to be made to http://localhost:3000 instead of http://localhost:8080.

Comment: This will allow all clients to access the API and the whole point of setting the origin would be nullified

Comment: this is just for running your application with the same host with different oring in your local machine. when you are putting your code in production it is not affecting your code.

Comment: In that case, it will work. I have edited your answer to include an alternate solution for cases where create-react-app is used.

Comment: At best, this is a band-aid solution aimed at development. The assumption here is that in production, the client web app and the API will be available at the same domain. In that event, you're no longer working with cross-domain requests and CORS is no longer needed. In reality, however, it's quite possible that the API's domain will in fact be different, even in production, and CORS will need to be properly configured.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have `credentials: true`, you should include the credentials in your fetch call:

```
fetch(url, {
  credentials: 'include'  
})
```

or

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/', true); 
xhr.withCredentials = true; 
xhr.send(null);
```

This will send the request with the headers set to `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`

without this, it will be rejected.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Comment: I believe I've already the Apollo equivalent of this

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/

Comment: Did you try setting credentials to false to rule out that this is a configuration issue on the backend?